# Prove that $(f \text{ continuous on } \mathbb{R}) \land (\forall x<c,\; f(x)<0)\land (\forall x>c,\; f(x)>0)\implies f(c)=0$

Tags: calculus, continuity, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

**Problem**

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ and $c\in\mathbb{R}$. Prove that
$$(f \text{ continuous on } \mathbb{R}) \land (\forall x<c,\; f(x)<0) \land (\forall x>c,\; f(x)>0) \implies f(c)=0$$

---

**My proof**

Since $f$ is continuous, we have that, for all $\varepsilon$, there is a $\delta$ such that for all $x\in [c-\delta,c+\delta]$
$$-\varepsilon \leq f(c)-f(x)\leq \varepsilon$$
This implies that $f(c)-\varepsilon\leq f(x)$

By contradiction, assume $f(c)>0$ (the case $f(c)<0$ is similar) and lets use $f(c)$ as our $\varepsilon$, then we have a $\delta$ such that $\forall x\in [c-\delta,c+\delta]$
$$0=f(c)-f(c)\leq f(x)$$
This says that $\forall x\in [c-\delta,c+\delta],\; f(x)\geq0$ but there are values on $[c-\delta,c+\delta]$ that are $>c$ and some that are $<c$ thus $f(x)$ cannot have the same sign for all of them. Contradicting  $\forall x\in [c-\delta,c+\delta],\; f(x)\geq 0\;\square$.

---

Is this a valid proof? I find it particularly simple given that I didn´t use the intermediate value theorem. (I'm not supposed to know it for this problem)

Comment: $0=f(c)-f(c)\leq f(x)$ is derived from $\displaystyle f(c)-\varepsilon \vert_{\varepsilon= f(c)}\leq f(x)$

Comment: Why don't you just use IVT?

Comment: It´s introduced on the very next chapter of the book (after this problem). I'm quite familiar with it but I wanted to solve the problem using only the information provided prior to the question.

Comment: Your work looks fine. I wouldn't worry about it being "too simple", because IVT is pretty much killing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof is correct. It could also be proven by the use of the IVT.